# How we can connect firefox os emulator or simulator to appium tool?

Tags: appium

I'm not able to get the list of connected devices using ADB commands..In Appium its possible connect firefox os emulator or simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Connecting FirefoxOS device should be an easy thing, [check](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/B2G_OS/Debugging/Connecting_a_Firefox_OS_device_to_the_desktop) you did it right.

But I doubt if Appium still supports Firefox OS, as Mozilla stopped Firefox OS support back in 2016. 
However it is still in the list of `platformName` [capability](https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps.md), so you may try it out but use old server version (back in the days of [2014](https://github.com/appium/appium/releases)) when it was supported.

Comment: But now B2G os is based on mozilla..What are the capbilty we need to set for firefox os..

Comment: ok, where did you read about Appium supports B2G? Officially it supports iOS, Android and Windows drivers. If there is any B2G/Firefox OS driver exists or not, its up to you implement JSON wire protocol based client and support it

Comment: Actually i have read its support firefox os..im not sure about b2g os.I thought they given B2G os is based on firefox.os..Do you have any idea What are the disered capabilities for fire fox os..?

Comment: Try out Android capabilities with the only change: "platformName": "FirefoxOS". And see how it goes. My guess it is no longer supported out of the box

Comment: I alerdy tried changing platformName to Firefoxos its throwing error,.i will try to download older version of appium and i'll check..